# Allow only dbonwer from accessing stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sa

I created **SQL DB**. and I want to allow only **"DB owner"** to access  stored procedures. I want to prevent all other users including **'s**a'  user from doing that . how to do that ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx ... plz have a look

Answer (score 1):

short answer: you can't.

long answer: sa is the owner of the whole server so cannot be cut out of anything on the server. you can prevent all other users (that does not have a sysadmin role) from using the stored procedures but again you have no way to lock out sa and/or any user with sysadmin role.

you may revoke permission to SA but SA can grant these permissions back easily.

actually you may lock out SA user if you disable SQL authentication or disable the user but anyway you cannot prevent other users with sysadmin role to interact with the stored procedures: this is by design.

please post a question with the actual requirement: this question looks like a solution you are trying to implement; maybe we can help you find a suitable solution **for the actual issue**.

as a side note, if you don't trust the admin of the server there is something wrong...

Comment: actually I want to install DB in the Customer server. but I want to prevent him from accessing  SPs @paolo

Comment: what you mean by 'accessing'? using them or reading the code?

Comment: there is not dependable way i'm aware of to do that. you can make things harder encrypting the stored procedures but they can be [decrypted](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60129/how-to-view-an-encrypted-view-or-stored-procedure) by the sysadmin.